# Loading Data with having Datafile and control file dynamically

Tags: batch-file, oracle11g, database-administration, sql-loader

I am loading data from a datafile dynamically into an Oracle table using sql loader. I also need to load data with having control file and datafile both dynamically, need to perform this in windows batch file.

I am new in working with windows batch file.

I tried something like having for loops

```
@echo off 
for %%C in ("C:\Example\Data*.ctl") do (for %%F in ("C:\Example\data-.csv")do ( sqlldr 'user/passwd@DBname' "CONTROL='%%C'" LOG='C:\Example\loader.log'"DATA='%%F'" ERRORS=10000 PARALLEL=TRUE DIRECT=TRUE
    goto AfterLoop
):afterloop
```

Can anyone give suggestion on this please...

Comment: The do needs spaces around `) do (` . It's unclear if your want to iterate each csv with each ctl or only ones matching the name. Hint: following a `(` and in front of `)` you can insert line breaks to make the code better readble.

Comment: Thank you....I need to load each csv with each ctl file...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know sqlldr and it's proper arguments but cmd will treat an equal sign as an argument separator so it may need to be escaped with a caret (if not quoted).

Using goto to break out of the for loops will have only the first ctl with the first csv executed.

```
@echo off 
for %%C in ("C:\Example\Data*.ctl") do (
  for %%F in ("C:\Example\data-.csv") do ( 
    sqlldr "user/passwd@DBname" "CONTROL='%%C'" LOG^=C:\Example\loader.log "DATA='%%F'" ERRORS^=10000 PARALLEL^=TRUE DIRECT^=TRUE
    goto AfterLoop
)
:afterloop
```

Comment: Well that reply isn't helpful. Debug in an open cmd window and temprorily change the `@Echo off` to  `@Echo on` and see what error messages show up if any.